# XML Generation in Java 1.3

Tags: java, xml

Yes, I am talking about Java 1.3 - I'm maintaining an application that for reasons beyond my control will not move in the short term.

There is a fair bit of XML generation going on using the boreland XML library, which makes XML generation quite longwinded.

I'm looking for a library, built in or third party. That provides a simple wrapper around XML node creation and file creation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JDom and the W3C DOM API for Java (org.w3c.dom.*) are good APIs for this. Depending on the structure of your schemas, you might be able to create a JAXB 1.0 (the older spec) mapping that will work on 1.3.

Comment: `org.w3c.dom` is also very long-winded for XML generaton.